# Create list from 2 numbers and 2 for loops

Tags: list, loops, scheme

I have 2 numbers let's say number1=5 and number2=3 and I want to create a list in this form

((1(1 2 3)) (2(1 2 3)) (3(1 2 3)) (4(1 2 3)) (5(1 2 3)))

So the number1 indicates the number of the elements  in the list and number2 indicates the total elements that will be as the second part of every element..

I have smth like this untill now

```
(define mylist '())

   (define (pushlist item item2)
  (do ((j 1 (+ j 1))) ((> j item2))
   (set! mylist(list mylist (list item j)))))



  (define (createlist number number2)
   (do ((j 1 (+ j 1))) ((> j number))
   (pushlist j number2)
    ))

  (createlist 5 3)
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.. It doesn't give the result I want.. It gives me this `(((((((((((((((() (1 1)) (1 2)) (1 3)) (2 1)) (2 2)) (2 3)) (3 1)) (3 2)) (3 3)) (4 1)) (4 2)) (4 3)) (5 1)) (5 2)) (5 3))`

Comment: As specified, your question is a bit ambiguous.  Would it be acceptable if, e.g., the `(1 2 3)` sublist was the _same_ list for element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this problem - for example, using explicit recursion, or using higher-order procedures. Your approach is not recommended, in Scheme you should try to avoid thinking about loops and mutation operations. Although it *is* possible to write such a solution, it won't be idiomatic. I'll try to explain how to write a more idiomatic solution, using explicit recursion first:

```
; create a list from i to n
(define (makelist i n)
  (if (> i n)
      '()
      (cons i (makelist (add1 i) n))))

; create a list from i to m, together with
; a list returned by makelist from 1 to n
(define (makenumlist i m n)
  (if (> i m)
      '()
      (cons (list i (makelist 1 n))
            (makenumlist (add1 i) m n))))

; call previous functions
(define (createlist number1 number2)
  (makenumlist 1 number1 number2))
```

Now, an even more idiomatic solution would be to use higher-order procedures. This will work in Racket:

```
; create a list from i to n
(define (makelist n)
  (build-list n add1))

; create a list from i to m, together with
; a list returned by makelist from 1 to n
(define (makenumlist m n)
  (build-list m
              (lambda (i)
                (list (add1 i) (makelist n)))))

; call previous functions
(define (createlist number1 number2)
  (makenumlist number1 number2))
```

See how we can avoid explicit looping? that's the Scheme way of thinking, the way you're expected to solve problems - embrace it!

Comment: Speechless.. Fantastic!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your `pushlist` procedure is doing what you you expect it to.

```
(define (pushlist item item2)
  (do ((j 1 (+ j 1)))
      ((> j item2))
    (set! mylist (list mylist (list item j)))))
```

If you have a list `(x y z)` and you want to push a new value `v` into it, you'd do

```
(set! lst (cons v lst))
```

because `(cons v (x y z)) == (v x y z)`.  By doing

```
(set! mylist (list mylist (list item j)))
```

you're making `mylist` always have exactly two elements, where the first is a deeper and deeper nested list.   [Óscar López's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19960861/1281433) gives a more idiomatic approach to this problem.  Here's  a similar idiomatic approach:

```
(define (range n)
  ; returns a list (1 ... n)
  (let rng ((n n) (l '()))
    (if (zero? n) 
        l
        (rng (- n 1) (cons n l)))))
```

If the sublists `(1 ... n)` can all be the same list (i.e., the actual list object is the same), then you can create it just once:

```
(define (createlist m n)
  (let ((sublist (range n)))
    (map (lambda (main)
           (list main sublist))
         (range m))))
```

Otherwise, if they need to be distinct, you can generate one for each of `1 ... m`:

```
(define (createlist m n)
  (map (lambda (main)
         (list main (range n)))
       (range m)))
```